# How to upload file using mechanize python?

Tags: python, file, upload, mechanize, txt

I need to upload a file(txt) in a form like this:

[image: press to upload file]

the structure of the add button is as follows:

[image: code of add button]

after upload I have to send the file with the send button:

[image]

the structure of the send button is as follows:

[image]

I searched and found only examples like this:

```
browser.select_form(name = 'formForm')
browser.form.add_file(open(directory))
response = browser.submit()
```

but I didn’t succeed, if anyone can help me thank you very much

Comment: _but I didn’t succeed_ Please provide a [mcve]. Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 1):

this is what you're looking for:

```
br.form.add_file(open(filename), 'text/plain', filename)
```

Comment: I tried it, I was unsuccessful. what is filename in this case?

Comment: whatever file you are tring to upload. suppose its an image, you would use "image.png" instead of just "filename".

Comment: And the path of file??

Comment: you would just put the path to the file?

Comment: I can't do it at all, do you have an example to show me?

Comment: suppose your file is called "image.png". You would use "image.png". If 'image.png" was in a folder named "images", you would use "images/image.png".